# Invoking an iOS build from a Windows PC

Tags: ios, iphone, macos

Can we build(Compile+Link+Build) an iOS project from a windows PC?. I want to remotely compile and build an iOS application from a windows PC through command. Is that possible ?

I know that it is possible to build an iOS application via commandline in ios using xCodeBuild. Can we do that remotely from a windows PC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use SSH to log into the Mac machine and run `xcodebuild`? That’s the essential core trick, and depending on your needs you can add more bells and whistles. For example the [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) continuous integration server can manage a “slave” Mac machine to build and test code, showing you the results.

Comment: Thanks Zoul, but can we automate the same from a windows machine using any scripts ?

Comment: Sure. Just write a script that logs to the Mac machine via SSH. I have no idea how scripting works on Windows, but surely there are many options.